# "illegal start of expression" using an if && statement inside of a boolean

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I don't know if it's because of the way I formatted the accesor methods or if you're just not allowed to use an if && statement in this situation but I just can't seem to figure out why I keep getting these two errors when trying to compile my code. Please help.

BankAccount.java:13: error: illegal start of expression
        if(id2.equals(c.getId()))&& pin2.equals(c.getPin())v = true;
                                 ^
BankAccount.java:13: error: ';' expected
        if(id2.equals(c.getId()))&& pin2.equals(c.getPin())v = true; 
                                                                   ^

```
public class BankAccount
{
private double balance;
private Customer c;
private boolean v;

public BankAccount(){
    balance=100;
    c=new Customer();
}

public boolean ValidAccount(String id2, String pin2){
    if(id2.equals(c.getId()))&& pin2.equals(c.getPin())v = true;
}

public BankAccount(Customer c1, double initial){
    balance=initial;
    c=c1;
}
public double checkBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public void deposit(double money){
    balance+=money;
}

public void withdraw(double money){
    balance-=money;
}

public Customer getCustomer(){
    return c;
}
public String toString(){
    return "" + c.getFirstName() + " "+ c.getFirstName() + balance + " " + 
c.getId() + " " + c.getPin(); 

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the **`()`** enclosing the whole expression.

```
    ---------------- Don't forget these -----------------
    v                                                   v
 if ( (id2.equals(c.getId()))&& pin2.equals(c.getPin()) ) 
 {
     v = true;
 }
```

**Edit:**

Since you declared your method `ValidAccount` to return a boolean, you must return something. Maybe you wanted this:

```
public boolean ValidAccount(String id2, String pin2){
    if ( (id2.equals(c.getId())) && pin2.equals(c.getPin()) )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**Note:** I would recommend you to follow Java naming conventions, read about it on Google. You should call methods like this: `someMethod(...)` and classes like `SomeClass`.

Comment: Thank you, that got rid of the first error but now i'm getting "BankAccount.java:14: error: missing return statement
 }
 ^" as an error

Comment: ^ So return something!

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean ValidAccount(String id2, String pin2){
    if(id2.equals(c.getId()))&& pin2.equals(c.getPin())v = true;
    return v; //<-- gotta return v
}
```

You are not returning a boolean here

Comment: Okay cool thanks guys, new to programming. Sorry for the noob questions lol.